# How to make my HTML page adapt to every resolution

Tags: html, css

I have a 1080p monitor and everything works fine here.But on other monitors with 1366x768 resolution the webiste doesnt look the same as it does with my monitor

## How can i make my website adapt to every monitor?

In article,i type the margin and height wrong to disable them,but if any case need them back i know where to go.

Here is the CSS code:

```
article{
    margsin:20px;
    hseight:100%;
    color:navy;
    }
footer{
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    font-size:12px;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    min-width:1920px;
    min-height:50px;
    }
div.all{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    min-width:1920px;
    min-height:1080px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    background:linear-gradient(white,lightblue);
    font-size:20px;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you meant by looking wrong. But for me, for bigger resolutions, e.g. 1366px or more, I find the content tend to spread out too much.

I like to add a wrap class. And rather than min-width, I usually add a max-width to constraint the content.

```
<div class="wrap"></div> 
.wrap {max-width: 1200px;}
```

Comment: By looking wrong i mean that with my code in smaller monitors,the page looks like it is zoomed in and you'll have to go around with the X-Y bars

Comment: ah, might be the min-width:1920px; Regardless of the screen resolution, this statement causes the width to be always 1920px or more, hence the y bar.  did you set the viewport? 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: No because we havent seen that in school yet,so what do i do just add the meta tag?

Comment: Do you use atom? I use that and install emmet package. Anything that could make me work faster.  I type out "doc", hit tab key on .html file. You will see this. 
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>

But yes, like what ijohnston says, use relative units, media queries to make it more responsive :)

Comment: No i dont know what that is..
Okay i switched to %.And trying to make something out of margin i think it will work

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/ use body {font-size:62.5%} for better control of rem (since most of us think in px) Personal opinion, but I think rem makes life easier :)

Comment: I think rem just helped me finish the project!!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you feel you need to make a site look good on bigger resolutions I suggest you read up on media queries and relative units instead of using pixels. Media queries will let you set a breakpoint (in your case a screen size) where you can apply new styles.
[You can read about them here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Relative units, such as %, em, rem or vw and vh will help your styles scale based on the width of the viewport. [You can read up on them here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units)

Comment: I didnt use those units because i wanted the exact resolution in pixels

Comment: Zach — he’s answering your question. How do you make your site adapt to different screen sizes? First and foremost, STOP using pixel sizing!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by ohers, [media queries](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) would be a good place to start. 
Also, moving away from pixels and perhaps over to things like `vh`, `vw`, `%`and more :-)